# Column does not take the measure indicated in elementor pro

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have a 100% column that when switching to tablet mode reduces itself. Although it indicates that it is 100%, it maintains the same reduced size.

On this site I only have elementor and elementor PRO v3.0.6 and installed with the Hello theme.

No other plugin installed.

[elementor error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLA0g.gif)

Comment: Hey, could you try to show us the rest of the attributes of the column? Have you checked its margin, padding? Its position? What you could also try to do is to display this page in your browser, and use dev tools (in tablet mode) to check if the error also happens outside of the elementor editor. If it does, you could try to see why it's not taking up the whole viewport by looking at its css and html attributes. If your website is not local, could you also provide us with a link to the page?